# How to get un-coded characters from .txt files in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, text

I'm a beginner, and i'm having trouble with getting uncoded characters from .txt files, i'm using the `open('file',mode='r')`
method and what's troubling me is that vowels and the 'ç' consonant aren't getting set as normal letters, but as a code, like so:

From text file:

"Que ele não mereça"

From the Python3 console:

"Que ele nÃ£o mereÃ§a\n"

i've looked online but i only found a way to eliminate those characters, instead of "não" it becomes 'no', how can i substitute them in a generic way? the .txt file could be anything.

Comment: You can specify an encoding. For example: `open('file',mode='r', encoding='utf8')`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: but it's also possible OP's *output* terminal does not support UTF8 ...

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i've tried that and it worked!! thanks for the help, you saved me